# Crack RSA by using user signatures

Tags: cryptography

Lets say I have a secret $s$ that is encrypted with a public key $(N,e)$. We know $e=35567$. However we don't know $N$.

We can ask the user to sign any message $m$ with his private key $(N,d)$ _ of course $d=e^{-1}\mod{\phi(N)}$ _

However the user is smart, if we tell him to sign $s$, he just won't do it.

How can I decrypt $s$ using this ?

**My Attempts**

What I tried to do is telling the user to sign $s\times2^e$ and then dividing the returned signed message by 2. However this fails because I did not reduce $s\times2^e$ modulo $N$ because I don't know $N$.

I tried getting $N$ by sending many message for the user to sign then compute some GCD of the messages but the calculations become so big that everything fails ...

Comment: some libraries accept larger values to encrypt and decrypt with RSA.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you know $N$?  This is part of the public key.  The attacker doesn't know the prime factors of $N$, but $N$ itself should be public.

You are asking for a chosen plaintext attack against RSA.   This is well known (though only against textbook RSA - it won't work if the message is padded properly).

If you want the user to sign $s$, you can choose any random $x$ and form $sx^e \mod N$ then if you can trick the user into signing it you get $s^d x \mod N$.  Your signature is $s^d$ and you can get it by dividing by your chosen value $x$.

I think this attack was originally due to Davida, if you want to look it up.

Comment: Without N, the attack sadly does not work, I send the user m and he does $m^d\mod{N}$ and that's it, no need for me to know $N$

Comment: rudeus123 The signature $m^d\mod N$ is not much use without $N$ because you also need $N$ to verify the signature.

Comment: I know it is just how the problem is asked sadly :-(